# Недопонимание в .NET-метках

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, удаление-метки, создание-метки

Есть некоторое недопонимание в .NET-метках:

- [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) (описание):

  - Ожидание: «.NET is a free, cross-platform, open source developer *platform* for building many different types of applications» ([источник](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet))
  - Реальность: Описание не самой .NET Platform, а её ответвления .NET Framework
- [.net-platform](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform): отсутствует (используется [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net))
- [.net-framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework): отсутствует (используется [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net))

Я думаю, что нужно разделить метку [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) на 2 части (саму метку удалить, т. к. может возникнуть путаница, даже если об этом написать в описании):

- [.net-platform](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-platform): Собственно, .NET Platform
- [.net-framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework): Собственно, .NET Framework

Как вы *считаете*, является ли это разделение оправданным?

Comment: Оно просто историческое видно, когда ещё только фреймворк был (и моно был нишевым, а кор в природе не было), поэтому можно актуализировать в соответствии с нынешним состоянием. Я бы не разделял метку на две (тем более если ещё и вопросы туда-сюда перекидывать), а просто поправил бы описание для .net. Причём отсутствие net-platform легко объясняется именно тем, что сама метка .net = .net-platform нужны ли специфично фреймворковские вопросы? Хм, кор и так отдельно, а в остальном вроде никто не путается.

Comment: @AK Про историю .NET я знаю, просто .NET Platform и .NET Framework – это не одно и тоже

Comment: @AK Как раз таки нет: .net = .net platform, .net = .net framework, .net = .net core, .net = .net 5. Этого мало?

Answer (score 1):

Разделить то нужно, но .net-platform выглядит слишком громоздким названием для метки. По мне, следует использовать ту же терминологию, что и официальная документация: просто [.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/), когда речь идет об общих элементах технологии, характерных для любой реализации, и [.NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/overview) / [.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/about), когда идет речь о конкретных реализациях. Соответственно, у нас нужно сделать следующее:

[.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) - отредактировать описание метки, так чтобы оно отражало современный смысл понятия .NET.

[.net-framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) - создать, повесить на несколько подходящих вопросов и добавить к ней старое описание метки [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) (также добавить к нему, что метку следует использовать только для вопросов о вещах, специфичных для .NET Framework - домены приложений, GAC, алгоритм привязки сборок на основе строгого имени и т.п.)

Сильно много править тут не придется, так как большинство вопросов в метке [.net] и сейчас не касаются ничего специфичного для .NET Framework.

Comment: Дело в том, что люди всё равно будут добавлять в свой вопрос метки [.net] и, например, [.net-core], хотя сам вопрос с самой платформой .NET никак не связан, а [.net-core] идёт как уточнение, что действие происходит именно в .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core уже скоро переименуют в .NET Framework 5, так что разделять платформу и фреймвёрк никакого смысла нет, всё это одно и то же.

Comment: Как и с win7, .net framework и .net core ещё будут некоторое время жить, да и неизвестно когда этот .net 5 выйдет (ещё может перенесут релиз)

Comment: @return Может, но уже седьмое превью вышло: https://habr.com/en/company/microsoft/blog/512544/ дальше уже релиз кандидаты будут.

Comment: @return, т. е. надо взять и просто так посортировать 4199 вопросов на 2 метки, которые в ближайшее время станут одной? Кстати, метка [tag:.net-core] существует.

Comment: @Qwertiy я о .net core ничего и не говорил) можно просто .net -> .net-framework и всё, а новые вопросы будут с норм. метками

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, не .NET Framework 5, а просто .NET 5